# Unrecognized selector on row "addTarget...", how to solve?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, unrecognized-selector

I have the following code:

```
self.firstStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CheckupStepTableViewCell.stepperValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

that crash only on my iPad users (sometime) in iOS 9 and 10. Error is:

[image: error image]

But I really don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: It looks like self.firstStepper is getting set to a UIView that is not a UIControl. addTarget is a method on UIControl.

Comment: Thanks Jim! You've indicated the right path. The problem was the storyboard in iPad mode where I had not updated module of my control's component. If you put comment as response I can approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like self.firstStepper is getting set to a UIView that is not a UIControl. addTarget is a method on UIControl.